# Как очистить только текст в буфере обмена?

Tags: c#, winapi, clipboard

`Clipboard.Clear` очищает весь буфер, а через `SetText` с аргументом `string.Empty` или `null`, выдает исключение. Как очистить только текст и ничего больше? Наверняка, нужно выполнять методы из WinAPI.

Comment: `if (Clipboard.ContainsText()) Clipboard.Clear();` - очистит буфер только в том случае, если он содержит текст.

Comment: Но там же одновременно и изображение может быть

Comment: @YD359 наскольлко я знаю, буфер виндовс хранит последний скопированный объект, представляя его разными вариантами (текст, объект и т.д.), по-этому нельзя просто взять и заменить текстовый вариант представления, оставив все остальные неизменными

Comment: А зачем? Если вам нужна картинка, вы можете запросить картинку. Вы не можете отредактировать только один тип данных в буфере не затронув остальное.

Comment: Из-за какого-то бага у меня картинка из буфера не вставляется, если в нем есть текст. Может, я ошибаюсь и просто каринка затерлась текстом, но мне всегда казалось, что хранится и текст и картинка отдельно.

Comment: Текст ошибки и код показывайте, рассказывайте ситауцию в деталях. Текст картинке не может мешать, так как буфер как вы уже в курсе, может содержать много форматов данных. Скорее всего в том, что вы пока не разобрались, как именно этот самый буфер обмена работает. Он, если что, достаточно сложный в своем устройстве. Но предположение что наличие одного формата данных мешает получение другого - неверно. Текущий вопрос можете удалить, потому что он про костыли, а не про решение проблемы.